# Zip and download files from external url in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 2+ files that are hosted on an external server. I want to write a rest controller which can zip all these files together and download them (without loading them into memory as files can be of large size).

Right now I know how to do this stuff if these files are present in my local. But I don't know how to do it with the above requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OkHttpClient and read Body as stream. Once you've all the `File`s in the local, you can Zip it as normally

```
  public static File downloadResource(String fileName, String url, String downloadFilePath) {
      OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
      OkHttpClient client = builder.readTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .connectTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
      Request downloadRequest = new Request.Builder().url(url).addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
              .addHeader("Authorization", "add any authorization").build();
      Response downloadResponse = null;
      try {
          downloadResponse = client.newCall(downloadRequest).execute();

          if (downloadResponse.code() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
   
              throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find the file  -" + fileName);
          }
          if (!downloadResponse.isSuccessful()) {
             
              throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find the file  -" + fileName);
          }

          File downloadedFile = new File(downloadFilePath);

          try (InputStream in = downloadResponse.body().byteStream();
               FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("finalZip.zip");
               BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
               ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);) {

              // not available on BufferedOutputStream
              zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
              IOUtils.copyLarge(in, zos);

          }

          return downloadedFile;

      } catch (ResourceAccessException hostException) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Unable to connect with Server");

      } catch (HttpClientErrorException | IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Unable to connect with Server", e);
      } finally {
          if (downloadResponse != null && downloadResponse.body() != null) {
              downloadResponse.body().close();
          }
      }
  }
```